# Does the random variable follow a Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let $N$ be the number of wars a country $C$ has participated in since year $Y$.  Suppose the times of the starts of these wars form a Poisson process with parameter $\mu$ from $Y$ to the present. What is the distribution of $N$?

My intuition is that $N \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$ but I am not certain. Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter is the rate $\mu$ at which events (traditionally called "births") happen, then $N$ is Poisson distributed with mean $\mu$ times the amount of time the process has been running.

Comment: I see! But suppose that you have observations $Y_1, \dots,, Y_n$ of starts of wars for country $C$ (and $Y< Y_1 < \dots < Y_n$. How would you compute the MLE for $\mu$ based on that data? I am having hard time seeing what the likelihood function would be, namely $f(\mu; {\bf Y})$.